# MySQL designing database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working actually on servers list and I'm wondering how can I design mysql table in the best way.
Index will render table with basic informations about server: address, port, players online, map, rank, ...
Server description, stats and other stuff will be in other subpage "more info about server"

In that case which design is better?

```
Servers(id, user_id, host, port, ...)
ServersInformations(id, server_id, players, map, ...)
```

Or just

```
Servers(id, user_id, host, port, players, map, rank)
```

and in

```
ServersInformations()
```

rest informations which will be rendered in subpage "more info about server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the tables in the database do not necessarily reflect your pages, but they reflect the relationships of your data.

If we take your first case where you have 2 tables, `Servers` and `ServerInformation`. You have a foreign key `ServerInformation.server_id` that (I presume) references `Servers.id`.

In this case what you are implying is that a `Server` could potentially have multiple entries in the `ServerInformation` table (i.e. a one-to-many relationship), all having the same `server_id` value, unless you make that `unique`, in which case it becomes a one-to-one relationship.

If you go for the second approach with one `Servers` table, you can still only get the fields you want for the index page. You will do a simple query that just gets the fields you need, for example: `select id, user_id, host, port from servers`

Unless you have a very specific reason for the first approach to separate the two tables (for example some `Server` entries don't have a `ServerInformation` entry, or you want some `ServerInformation` entries to have their `server_id` set to `null` if you set it to `nullable`), probably the one table approach is more adequate.

Comment: if the answer is adequate, kindly selected it as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

What information goes on each page is really irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the type of data that you'll be storing. You should store all information about the server in a single table, aside from any columns that will contain multiple values.

For example, if your `players` column is just a count for the number of players, then this can be a part of the `Servers` table.

If you `players` column acually contains a list of players, you should make a new table for it, e.g.

`ServerPlayers(id, playerName, ServerId)`